# Regex to match prefix/category/optional page number

Tags: php, regex

I just don't seem to have any luck with regular expressions !  I've written a Wordpress plugin which grabs (in theory) a category and an optional page number from a url but I just can't get it to match the url pattern.

The url's are of the format:

```
Bikes/Hybrid-Bikes

Bikes/Hybrid-Bikes/1

Bikes/Hybrid-Bikes/2
```

etc

and:

```
Bikes/Mountain-Bikes

Bikes/Mountain-Bikes/1

Bikes/Mountain-Bikes/2
```

and so on.

Here's the regex I'm trying to use:

```
   Bikes/([^/]+)(?:/(\d+))?
```

which matches the category but not the page number.  I'm sure I'm 99% of the way there but I just can't figure this out !

Thanks in advance

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close indeed.

Add the start and end (`^$`) markers to complete the expression:

```
^Bikes/([^/]+)(?:/(\d+))?$
```

PHP working example:

```
$string = "Bikes/Hybrid-Bikes/1";

var_dump(
    preg_match(
        "~^Bikes/([^/]+)(?:/(\d+))?$~i",
        $string
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it's not working.  It doesn't match /Bikes but it does match /Bikes/Category but not when there's a page number on the end.  I've uninstalled and re-installed the plugins and flushed the permalink rewrite rules too.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: It works for me. I'll paste the code that works for me. You never said to match "Bikes", and your examples don't imply you need to either.

Comment: Thanks Madara, the Bikes is a prefix.  I did mention it in the title but not the body of the question.  Apologies for that.

Comment: Madara, I tried your example but only int(1) as the output so I split made the preg_match into this: preg_match("~^Bikes/([^/]+)(?:/(\d+))?$~i",$string, $matches); and then var_dump($matches) and I can see that it's working fine.  Thank you.  But it's not in Wordpress.  Perhaps there's a conflict with another rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex to match your page number:

```
Bikes/([^/]+)?/?(\d+)?
```

You can validate RegExps on http://regexpal.com - my Test data were:

> Bikes/
>
> Bikes/Hybrid-Bikes
>
> Bikes/Hybrid-Bikes/1
>
> Bikes/Hybrid-Bikes/2

Comment: Hey, your second group catches /2 in Bikes/Hybrid-Bikes/2

Comment: Not sure what you mean Robert ?

Comment: Thanks robert, I modified the regexp and pointed the question opener to an interactive regexp tester.

Comment: What I meant is that Gregor's Regex(before he's edited it) Bikes/([^/]+)(/\d+)? was wrong and matched the second '/' too :) You're welcome.

Comment: Ah, ok !  You guys are quicker than me !

Answer (score 0):

```
^\w+\/\w+-?\w+\/?\d?$
```

Tested in robular try it out